# Hybris vs. Demandware, architectural main differences

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, demandware

What are the core architectural main differences between `Hybris` and `Demandware`?

Answer (score 4):

The core main difference:

- DW is SaaS and you write your code with old JS dialect (Rhino version) on top of DW core just with limited access to API.
- Hybris is Framework and you write your code with Java together with full access to Java language features.